# finding average by ignoring null values from denominator in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, weighted-average

we have table like
[image]

now we have to calculate the average on the base of weightage for col1,col2,col3,col4 as 0.5,1.0,0.5,1.0 respectively
so the the formula look like `((col1*0.5)+(col2*1)+(col3*0.5)+(col4*1))/(0.5+1+0.5+1)`
but if the value of any column is null it should not be considered in denominator
e.g for row 2 average formula should be

`((0.398160315*0.5)+(nvl(col2,0)*1)+(0*0.5)+(nvl(col4,0)*1))/(0.5+0.5) =0.199080161`

calculating in sql
i can handle null in numerator by nvl(col1,0)
but how can i handle it in denominator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`nvl2()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm):

```
(0.5*nvl(col1, 0) + 1.0*nvl(col2, 0) + 0.5*nvl(col3, 0) + 1.0*nvl(col4, 0),
 0.5*nvl2(col1, 1, 0) + 1.0*nvl2(col2, 1, 0) + 0.5*nvl2(col3, 1, 0) + 1.0*nvl2(col4, 1, 0)
)
```

Usually, I prefer `coalesce()` to `nvl()`.  But `nvl()` seems reasonable when used in conjunction with `nvl2()`.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle AVG() function can be used to achieve your purpose. May look at the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions011.htm) for more information on usage. The AVG() function ignores NULL values. For example, the average of 2, 4, and NULL is (2 + 4) /2 = 3. Hope that helps.